# can grails formRemote call controller action in onComplete?

Tags: grails

Can I have formRemote to call controller action after the request has fully completed ? preferably in onComplete, but how ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<g:formRemote onComplete="doTheMonkey();" onSuccess="withMe()"> </g:formRemote>
```

All the possible events are listed on the documentation page, please take a look at [them](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formRemote.html).

Comment: Thanks. But not exactly what I wanted. It says: 'onComplete (optional) - The **JavaScript** function to call'. I would need it to call a procedure in grails _controller_